# Which approach is better : any(list) v/s iterate list and return, or both are same?

Tags: python, any

Does any function works similar to logic mentioned in f2() below. Or does it need to create the list first and then iterate thru elements?

```
iplist = [1,2,3]
ipfilter = [3]

def f1():
  filtered = False
  if any([ip in ipfilter for ip in iplist]):
    filtered = True
  return filtered

def f2():
  for ip in iplist:
    if ip in ipfilter:
      return True
  return False
```

Does the first function need to first create the list and then pass it to any(), while second functions does early return? In terms of performance is f2 better choice?

Comment: If a value in iplist is found in ipfilter return true?

Comment: In `f1()`, the `filtered` variable is superfluous. You can just return the result of the `any()` function. If order are duplicate items are insignificant, then you can use sets instead of lists and get the intersection `set1.intersection(set2)`

Comment: Does not the first function need to first create the list and then pass it to any(), while second functions does early return? In terms of performance isn't f2 better?